# How to access embedded ArangoDB from desktop application?

Tags: c++, graph-databases, arangodb

I have copied ArangoDB dlls into my application and loaded them. I have trouble accessing ArangoDB API's to start server from C++ application. Has anybody able to access embed ArangoDB from C++ application.

Answer (score 3):

ArangoDB's API is HTTP-based. For that, `arangod` (the server binary) needs to be running, which hosts a web server that serves requests to the [RESTful API](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/HTTP/). There are [drivers](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-drivers/) for various languages which make it easier to interact with the server. There is also a binary transport protocol called [VelocyStream](https://github.com/arangodb/velocystream), which is supported by the official Java driver. It is still a server-client model however.

ArangoDB is currently not designed to be embedded. It's not impossible to do, but you would have to do quite some coding work.

Also see the related question: [How to embed ArangoDB in a desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913010/how-to-embed-arangodb-in-a-desktop-application)